# Wifi does not connect automatically on login in 17.10

Tags: networking, network-manager

I just upgraded to 17.10 today. Mostly things are working great, but there are a few minor issues. Previously, in 17.04, whenever I logged in the wifi would automatically connect and my VPN would start. Now, in 17.10, on log in I have no wifi connectivity. The wifi shows as "Wifi not connected". If I then drill in, click on "select network" and choose my wifi manually it all works perfectly and my VPN starts as expected. If I click on "Wifi Settings" for my network the "Connect automatically" check box is checked. How do I get my wifi to start automatically?